# Understanding what Electrode Impedance values mean on Spec sheet

Tags: voltage, sensor, impedance, biopotential, electrode

I want to understand what the electrode impedance values given on spec sheet mean. Just looking to gain a general understanding and what voltages/ currents I can or cannot use. The electrodes are used to record voltage spikes of around 50-90 mV.

"""Electrode Diameter: 10 um or 30 um
   Electrode impedance: <100 kilo ohms for 30 um electrodes....250-400 kilo ohms 
   for 10 um electrodes"""

The link to the data sheet can be found here:
http://www.multichannelsystems.com/sites/multichannelsystems.com/files/60StandardMEA_Layout.pdf

Comment: What is your intended use?  Without looking, those are likely recording electrodes,  and not great for passing DC current

Comment: The lower the impedance, the wider diameter chunk of brain you'll see signals from.

Comment: My intended use is for recording small voltage signals(50-90 mV) from tissue samples. Would you guys consider this relatively low or high impedance?

Comment: Low impedance, if you're looking for single neurons, one at a time.  The higher impedance option is probably OK for capturing a few units per tip, and the lower impedance would be for a wider area